# Processing RestKit Response to get params not in entity

Tags: ios, restkit

I have an entity Comments. When I perform a rest operation, i get a response which has fields such as 
{
"status": "succeed"
}
I want to process these fields to know if the operation was successful or not but I dont want to add status to comment class because it doesnt belogn there.

```
RKObjectManager *sharedRKObjectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [sharedRKObjectManager managedObjectStore];
// Create a mapping for the comment entity
RKEntityMapping *responseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:ENTITY_COMMENT inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"comment_id":    @"commentId"
                                                      }];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                   pathPattern:COMMENT
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Is that the full response JSON? Or you get a comment and a status back?

Comment: I just get the status that the result of the operation was successful .. for example "like" operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a plain `RKObjectMapping` to a custom class or an `NSDictionary` and with the single `status` key. Then you should get a simple single item in the mapping result.